# Error message while installing Windows 10 - ASUS X540SA

Tags: windows-10, bsod, windows-installation

I have been trying to solve a problem for about a week on my ASUS X540SA which originally had Windows 10 installed. I installed Kali Linux, but then wanted to install Windows 7 [as detailed in my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1309629/during-installation-windows-failed-to-start-a-recent-hardware-or-software-chan).

Afterwards I tried to install Windows 10 because many users wrote that it is not possible to install Windows 7.

After I popped in the usb drive and booted from it, this popped up:

> Recovery
>
> Your PC needs to be repaired
>
> The operating system couldn't be loaded because the system registry
>   file is missing or contains errors.
>
> File: \windows\system32\config\system Error Code: 0xc000000d
>
> You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If
>   you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device),
>   contact your system administrator or PC manufacturer.

At the bottom of the last error message it also said:

> Press Enter to try again; Press F8 for Startup Settings. After pressing these buttons the screen just refreshed and showed the same message again

This message popped up directly after the Windows logo appeared. It did not appear after the language selection menu of the Windows setup.

Comment: This is extremely similar to [your previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1309629/during-installation-windows-failed-to-start-a-recent-hardware-or-software-chan); there is no need to duplicate that information here (particularly as you considered that part of the problem answered)- it's quite confusing.

Comment: This is not the same problem. If this confuses you just stop looking at it.

Comment: On the contrary, now that [I have edited it](https://superuser.com/posts/1310015/revisions) I believe it is much clearer, as it only asks about one problem; which I did to make it easier on the other folks reading this question in the hopes that would it benefit you by making it easier to answer :)

Comment: Some questions: what size is your USB drive? Have you tested that the USB drive will boot in another machine? Do you have *Secure Boot* enabled in UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have solved the problem.